# Given $M\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $v_1,v_2\in\mathbb{R}^n,$ find $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ such that $Mv_1=Av_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that we are given a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and two vectors $v_1,v_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Under which conditions there exists a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ such that $Mv_1=Av_2$?

In general such matrix does not always exist (say, if $v_2$ is a zero vector and $Mv_1$ is not a zero vector, then, clearly, no such $A$ exists) and so the question is about sufficient conditions under which such matrix exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear map $v \mapsto \frac{\langle v, v_2 \rangle}{\langle v_2, v_2 \rangle} Mv_1$ maps $v_2$ to $Mv_1$ unless $v_2 = 0$. So the answer is: always as long as $v_2 \neq 0$.

Of course, if $Mv_1 = 0$, then also $v_2 = 0$ works.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a linear map $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ that takes $v_2$ to $v_1$ unless $v_2=0$ and $v_1\ne0$. For example, $B:=\frac{1}{|v_2|^2}v_1v_2^T$.

Then for $A:=MB$, $Av_2=MBv_2=Mv_1$.